# How to populate a Grid programatically in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wpfdatagrid

I have a Grid I am trying to create and populate programatically in Silverlight. However, all of the items just default to spot "0, 0" in the grid despite my efforts. This is what I have:

```
Grid holdingGrid = new Grid();
int row = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Expander expander = new Expander();
   holdingGrid.Children.Add(expander);
   Grid.SetRow(expander, row);
   Grid.SetColumn(expander, 0);
   row++;
}
```

But this still causes all of the items to pile up in the first row and the first column. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you set row definitions for your grid?

Comment: Ha ha, that would do it. I added the row definitions and it works now. I can't believe I forgot that!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Grid holdingGrid = new Grid();
int row = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   Expander expander = new Expander();
   holdingGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
   holdingGrid.Children.Add(expander);
   Grid.SetRow(expander, row);
   Grid.SetColumn(expander, 0);
   row++;
}
```